# Populate ComboBoxes with Nested sub-folders

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

I'm trying to populate two comboboxes with the folders nested under one of my inboxes. The folders are under inbox > folder > folder > targertfolder.

With the target folder being folders with suffix checked under the Sub Checksubfolders.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim inbox As Outlook.folder
    Dim subfolder As Outlook.folder

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inbox = ns.Folders("**email@email.co.uk**").Folders("Inbox")
    Set subfolder = inbox.Folders("PENIEL GREEN N.HOME").Folders("2023")
    CheckSubfolders subfolder.Folders

    If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    End If

    If ComboBox2.ListCount > 0 Then
        ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub


Private Sub CheckSubfolders(subfolders As Outlook.Folders)
    For Each subfolder In subfolders
        If Not subfolder Is Nothing Then
            If Mid(subfolder.Name, Len(subfolder.Name) - 7, 8) = "PGNH Rx" Then
                ComboBox1.AddItem subfolder.Name
            ElseIf Mid(subfolder.Name, Len(subfolder.Name) - 10, 11) = "PGNH Triage" Then
                ComboBox2.AddItem subfolder.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It generates an error:

> -2147221233 - The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

The userform is still then generated with no folders present in either combobox.

Comment: Which line of code exactly gives the error message?

Comment: No line was being indicated once the error elements were commented out, I did try Resume next but that went no where - I have however amended to use the Namespace.Stores property which is producing my userform without any error but still not getting the subfolders I require to appear in the comboboxs

Comment: If you want to find which line of code gives the error message you need to remove all `OnError` statements from the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to consider adding [On Error Resume Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) in the `CheckSubfolders` method to make sure that code will continue iterating over all other folders in the loop if any folder is failed, so your combo-boxes will be filled with folder names anyway.

But I suppose the error comes from the following piece of code:

```
Set inbox = ns.Folders("**email@email.co.uk**").Folders("Inbox")
Set subfolder = inbox.Folders("PENIEL GREEN N.HOME").Folders("2023")
```

Use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile. After you've found the required store (see [Store.DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.displayname)) you can get the `Inbox` folder by using the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Finally, try to remove the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` line in the code to find out which line of code exactly gives the error, so you could fix that quickly.